# Replacing a While loop with AutoResetEvent for blocking a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Recently, I was finally able to make a separate thread work. Now I am trying to master synchronization.

As far as I know, pausing a thread with `ThreadName.Suspend()` is not a good idea. At fist I used a `While` loop to block the thread. Later I noticed that this consumes resources, so now I am trying to replace the loop with an `AutoResetEvent`.

Here is some code (tell me if you the full code):

```
private void combTester(object sender, EventArgs e)//happens in a timer, because it manipulates the GUI
{
    if (!timer2Block)
    {
        //stuff happens
        genBlock = false;//unblocks the thread
        timer2Block = true;//blocks itself
        //debugging stuff happens
    }
    if (done)
        timer2.Enabled = false;
}

private void combGenerator(int currEl, int begVal)
{
    //setting a variable
    for (int c = begVal; c <= currEl + totalCells - maxCells; c++)
    {
        while (genBlock && !abortTime)
        {
            if (abortTime)
                return;
        }
        genBlock = true;//blocks itself
        //some recursive stuff happens,
        //because of which I was forced to use a thread instead of timers
    }
}
```

I tried different places to put the `Wait()` and `Set()` methods, but both the tread and the timer get blocked and I don't know how to debug the program.

So, how can I replace the `While` loop with `AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to have a "pause" control for the worker thread then you should use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx): keep the event signaled, and reset it when you want the thread to pause:

```
private void combGenerator(int currEl, int begVal)
{
    for (int c = begVal; c <= currEl + totalCells - maxCells; c++)
    {
        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You can now pause/unpause the `combGenerator` thread by doing `manualResetEvent.Reset()` and `manualResetEvent.Set()` correspondingly.

This can be further expanded to include an "abort" signal by throwing in another `ManualResetEvent` (this could also be an `AutoResetEvent`, but as it's only going to do something once the distinction is not important):

```
    var events = new[] { abortEvent, pauseEvent }; // order MATTERS!
    for (int c = begVal; c <= currEl + totalCells - maxCells; c++)
    {
        var index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(events);
        if (index == 0) {
            // abort!
        }

        // do stuff
    }
```

The magic here happens inside [`WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx). This method will wait for any of the events to become signaled and return the *smallest index among the events that were signaled, if more than one*. This is extremely important, as it will allow us to determine if we should abort.

During normal operation `abortEvent` will not be signaled and `pauseEvent` will be, so `WaitAny` will immediately return `1`. If `pauseEvent` is reset then `WaitAny` will block until one of the events is again signaled. And if `abortEvent` is signaled then `WaitAny` will return `0`, which is the cue to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another flag that checks whether it is recursive call or not, based on which you can decide to continue, or wait.

Example:

```
static int recCount = 0;
private void combGenerator(int currEl, int begVal)
{
        //setting a variable
        for (int c = begVal; c <= currEl + totalCells - maxCells; c++)
        {
            while (genBlock && !abortTime and recCount < 1)
            {
                if (abortTime)
                    return;
            }
            genBlock = true;//blocks itself
            recCount ++;
            //some recursive stuff happens,
            //because of which I was forced to use a thread instead of timers
          //after all the stuff is done
        recCount--;
    }
}
```